# How to access indexs of binary numpy array column_wise using argwhere function

Tags: python, numpy

```
for example, I have a numpy array-like

    import numpy as np
    x=np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

current output:
ind=np.argwhere(x)
#the accessed indexes are row-wise is it possible to access in column_wise

```
required output:

     [[0 0]
     [4 0]
     [0 1]
     [3 1]
     [2 2]
     [1 3]
     [2 3]
     [3 3]
     [0 4]
     [1 5]
     [2 6]
     [4 6]
     [3 8]]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.nonzero(cond))`.  That is it takes the tuple of arrays created by `nonzero/where`, and makes a 2 column array.  And yes,`nonzero` traverses the array in `C/row` order (see the docs).  `argsort` could be used to resort the array on the 2nd column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transpose and swap the columns.

```
ind = np.argwhere(x.T)[:, [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This function also give the same output with element value :

```
import scipy as sp
sp.sparse.csc_matrix(x)
```